# How can I add/ view Google Contact info for email sender within Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I'd like to be able to view Notes for a particular contact within Gmail.

1. Click on email from or to them.
2. One-Click ADD to Contacts (if not already IN contact)
3. Next time I click on an email from/to them, I see their contact info (or more specifically NOTES) within Gmail.

I searched the Chrome Addons and Google Searched for "view contact within gmail".
I also asked Google Support.

Comment: What is the question? When you clarify that also add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Answer (score 0):

[Google Contacts Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/contacts%20-for-gmail/cnaibnehbbinoohhjafknihmlopdhhip?hl=en) has a free version that allows you to add 20 contacts/month.